# Sending HTTP to local FiddlerCore

Tags: c#, proxy, fiddler, fiddlercore

I'm tring to build a proxy server to handle local request.
For example - capture web browser printing request and sending them to the appropriate LAN printer.
My idea so far is to host the FiddlerCore engine in a Windows Service.
This is my code:

```
private static void Main()
{
    FiddlerApplication.OnNotification += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("** NotifyUser: " + e.NotifyString);
    FiddlerApplication.Log.OnLogString += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("** LogString: " + e.LogString);
    FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += oSession => { Console.WriteLine("Before request for:\t" + oSession.fullUrl); oSession.bBufferResponse = true; ParseRequest(oSession); };
    FiddlerApplication.BeforeResponse += oSession => Console.WriteLine("{0}:HTTP {1} for {2}", oSession.id, oSession.responseCode, oSession.fullUrl);
    FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += oSession => Console.WriteLine("Finished session:\t" + oSession.fullUrl);

    Console.CancelKeyPress += Console_CancelKeyPress;
    Console.WriteLine("Starting FiddlerCore...");
    CONFIG.IgnoreServerCertErrors = true;
    FiddlerApplication.Startup(8877, true, true);
    Console.WriteLine("Hit CTRL+C to end session.");

    Object forever = new Object();
    lock (forever)
    {
        Monitor.Wait(forever);
    }
}

private static void ParseRequest(Session oSession)
{
    switch (oSession.host)
    {
        case "localhost.":
            Console.WriteLine("Handling local request...");
            break;
    }
}

private static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Shutting down...");
    FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
    Thread.Sleep(750);
}
```

My question:
The `ParseRequest` function can recognize local requests (i.e. http://localhost./print?whatever), but how can I stop the proxy from relaying them forward (parsing and executing the print request but not getting the 404 page)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution myself:

In the `BeforeRequest` callback, a `Fiddler.Session` object is passed as an argument.
When calling its `utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer` function, the request is not relayed to any server but handled locally.

So, my new `ParseRequest` function is as follow:

```
private static void ParseRequest(Session oSession)
{
    if (oSession.hostname != "localhost") return;

    Console.WriteLine("Handling local request...");
    oSession.bBufferResponse = true;
    oSession.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
    oSession.oResponse.headers.HTTPResponseStatus = "200 Ok";
    oSession.oResponse["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    oSession.oResponse["Cache-Control"] = "private, max-age=0";
    oSession.utilSetResponseBody("<html><body>Handling local request...</body></html>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see you helping many people with Fiddler so your confirmation helps me.